# python Regex match till word if word found else match complete string and match group will be greater then 0

Tags: python, php, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am writing a regex to match string till specific word if word is in string else need to match full string. and match result should be group 1.
here word is: -my-word

mylaptop-my-word >  mylaptop  (group1 match)

mylaptop         > mylaptop   (group1 match)

mylaptop-my-word-hello-my-word > mylaptop-my-word-hello (group1 match)

so far I tried this:

```
([\s\S]+)-my-word|([\s\S]+)
```

but it giving me

mylaptop-my-word >  mylaptop  (group1 match)

mylaptop         > mylaptop   (group2 match)

Need to be group1 match

Comment: `(?s)^(?:(?!-my-word).|-my-word(?=.*-my-word))+`? Note in PHP it is as simple as `(?s)^(?|(.*)-my-word|(.*))`

Comment: hi, i am using python and  match pattern comes in group 0 , need to be in group greater then 0

Comment: It is not a problem. Add parentheses, `(?s)^((?:(?!-my-word).|-my-word(?=.*-my-word))+)`. What is the programming language you are going to use it in? PHP or Python? If Python, `re` or `regex`?

Comment: thank a lot bro , its working as excepted, I am using python with re.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?s)^((?:(?!-my-word).|-my-word(?=.*-my-word))+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/llsjgR/1).

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - a `re.DOTALL` inline modifier flag
- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?!-my-word).|-my-word(?=.*-my-word))+` - one or more occurrences of:

  - `(?!-my-word).` - any char that is not a starting point of the `-my-word` char sequence
  - `|` - or
  - `-my-word(?=.*-my-word)` - `-my-word` that is followed with another `-my-word` after any zero or more chars as many as possible